# Attach File Funcion for Common people

Tags: customization, plugin-recommendation, comments, attachments

How can i allow my visitors that they can attach files like word text pdf with their comments or can allow attach file to register users
is their any plugin or any other way for achieving this task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used it, but this might be what you're looking for:

- [Easy Comment Uploads<sup>*­Wordpress Plugin*</sup>](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-comment-uploads/)